# Enviar e-mail utilizando conta do cpanel e PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, yii, cpanel

estou tentando enviar um e-mail utilizando minha conta do cpanel e a classe phpmailler porém não estou obtendo exito , o código que estou utilziando é o mesmo da documentação do PHPMailler , como devo proceder? , algém teria um código fucnional para compartilhar? , obrigado.

```
require_once(Yii::app()->basePath . '/components/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true); // create a new object
        $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 4; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
        $mail->Host = "vps.meudominio.com.br";
        $mail->Port = 25;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Username = "contato@meudominio.com.br";
        $mail->Password = "testeste";
        $mail->SetFrom("contato@meudominio.com.br");
        $mail->Subject = "Testesteaste";
        $mail->Body = "<body> <img  width='1px' height='1px' src='http://www.testesteste.com.br' /> <h3>hu3hu3h3u3hu</h3> TEEEESTE!!!!</body>";
        $mail->AddAddress("email@gmail.com");

        if(!$mail->Send())
        {
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }else{

        }
        exit;
```

Comment: Primeiramente seja bem-vindo ao Stackoverflow em Português, confira o Tour para aproveitar melhor os recursos que o mesmo oferece: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour. Segundo, precisamos que você edite a sua pergunta com o código que você já tem disponível e não está funcionando.

Comment: Esta retornando algum erro? Utilizo o arquivo php `class.phpmailer.php` e não `PHPMailAutoload.php` como no seu caso.

Comment: Aparentemente a porta está errada, 25 é para smtp sem autenticação para `tls` deve ser outra. Tente mudar para 465

Comment: Tente com a porta 587 usando o mesmo código postado.

Answer (score 1):

No meu exemplo você terá que deixar a extensão `openssl habilitada`, e a porta 465 deverá estar  aberta no seu servidor.

**Exemplo de envio para Gmail:**

```
<?php

require_once("PHPMailerAutoload.php");
define('GUSER', 'seuemail@gmail.com'); // <-- Insira aqui o seu email
define('GPWD', 'senhaqui');  // <-- Insira aqui a senha do seu email

$Vai = "Testando o envio de email, você pode excluir essa mensagem, apenas me avise que chegou com sucesso, obrigado.";

function smtpmailer($para, $de, $de_nome, $assunto, $corpo) {
   global $error;
   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail->IsSMTP();  // Ativar SMTP
   $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;  // Debugar: 1 = erros e mensagens, 2 = mensagens apenas
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // Autenticação ativada
   $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // SSL REQUERIDO pelo GMail
   $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // SMTP utilizado
   $mail->Port = 465;    // A porta 465 deverá estar aberta em seu servidor
   $mail->Username = GUSER;
   $mail->Password = GPWD;
   $mail->SetFrom($de, $de_nome);
   $mail->Subject = $assunto;
   $mail->Body = $corpo;
   $mail->AddAddress($para);
   if (!$mail->Send()) {
      $error = 'Mail error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
      return false;
   } else {
      $error = 'Mensagem enviada!';
      return true;
   }
}

// Insira abaixo o email que irá receber a mensagem, o email que irá enviar (o mesmo da variável GUSER),
// o nome do email que envia a mensagem, o Assunto da mensagem e por último a variável com o corpo do email.

if (smtpmailer('emailDeQuemVaiReceber@hotmail.com.br', GUSER, 'Gabriel', 'Teste de envio', $Vai)) {
   echo 'seu imagem foi enviada';
}
if (!empty($error)) {
   echo $error;
}
?>
```

Comment: Para o Gmail eu consigo enviar , só para contas do cpanel que dá erro, você sabe dizer se é alguma configuração do cpanel ?, já testou em alguma conta do cpanel?

Comment: @talles_jp nunca enviei para cpanel, estes emails utilizam alguma porta especifica ?

Comment: @talles_jp de qualquer forma habilite o debug para ver  qual mensagem de erro retorna.

Comment: o erro é timeout 300 segundos, nada em especial.

Comment: seta `   set_time_limit(0);` no começo da página e aguarda até dar outro erro. você esta enviando anexos também ?

Comment: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Comment: @talles_jp certeza que a extensão openssl esta habilitada no seu php.ini ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31518/discussion-between-talles-jp-and-gabriel-rodrigues).

Comment: Antes de continuar com o SSL sugiro tentar a porta 587. A porta 25 só é usada atualmente para comunicação entre servidores de e-mail.